# When I connect the database Exception occur-System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqlite-net

**When Connection is open this Exception occur**

Code is:--

```
 SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
                connection.Open();
                Helper helper = new Helper(cmd);
helper.BeginTransaction();
```

Comment: Hello! Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074585/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-ot

It seems like your problem can be a lot of things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.AccessViolationException with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951201/system-accessviolationexception-with-sqlite)

Comment: @Ayush SQLite does not allow parallel writes. Just write from a single thread. (With databases, the bottleneck is likely to be the I/O anyway.)
Can you write the code without the "Helper" class (which seems to be an multi-threaded-class)?

Comment: Helper helper = new Helper(cmd);
helper.BeginTransaction();

Both two line replace with method 

   try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "begin transaction;";
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }

It gives Exception of : **Database is not open **  When i open connection in a thread

Comment: @Mr.Turtle :please help

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you are calling "connetion.Open()"? It seems like you have a problem with your connection.
Can you post the entire error stacktrace?